# Xcode7 :Simulator in use ios 9

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

I am getting this error with Xcode7.

```
Xcode cannot launch apps on the simulated device “iPhone 5”,
as it is currently running app with pid 3626 on “iPhone 6s Plus”.
Only one simulated device may be used at a time
```

1. I am not running any other app but the simulator still shows the message above.
2. I restarted XCode but it still did not work.
3. There are no active processes running for iOS simulator in the activity monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Close the simulator (cmd+Q) and retry.

Also, make sure that another Xcode project is not using it.

Comment: not woring.. i restarted xcode.still didnot work also thee is no process running for ios simulator in activity monitor

Answer (score 0):

Restarting xcode worked for me.